# Asking for a change in rules to get a MS rather than end the program with no degree

Tags: phd, graduate-school, masters, computer-science

I am in a weird spot. I have been a PhD student for 1.5 years and in May 2018 it will be 2 full years. I already have an MS in the same subject from another school. I was told recently that I will be asked to leave the program at the end of this semester due to lack of research funding. I asked if I can be given a MS instead since I fulfilled all the requirements for that but that cannot be done as I already have a MS from in the same subject from a different place. I will try really hard to see if I can plead some leniency but I just wanted to ask if you people know of cases where students were able to plead successfully. I am really scared because if I am terminated from this program, I will be forced to leave USA because I won't have any status and I will have nothing to show for these 2 years.

Comment: Is "this" semester in May 2018?

Comment: What is your exact question? You wrote you "just wanted to ask" something, so, do actually ask it!

Comment: Try to find a different MS  related to your PhD instead, so that you can "bend" the definition of your work such that it matches the MS close enough. That can easily be possible - after convincing, and with support of the administration.

Answer (score 18):

In addition to the suggestion given in Nicole Hamilton's answer, and provided that you are making good progress in your degree, you still have several options:

- You could see if someone else in the department has funding to support another student.
- You could see if colleagues in other departments at your institution doing work related to your thesis area.
- You could ask if the department will help you in transferring to another program.

The big question here is why you're being let go. If it's really that funds are low, and it's through no fault of your own, then the department owes you the right to continue in the program, or help you to continue your studies. On the other hand, if they're saying "we don't want to spend more money on you," then it'll be a lot harder to get help.

As far as awarding a duplicate degree, that's probably not decided at the department level, but instead probably requires a higher-level signoff.

Comment: thanks. it is a bit of both. I am frantically searching for new people but the odds are low. I am just wondering, is the decision to award a degree the prerogative of the department in which case if able to convince them, they might waive the rule. I know it may vary between places but have you ever come across a case where an exception to a similar case was made.

Comment: @anon_945500: See my edit above.

Comment: "then the department owes you the right to continue in the program" based on what?

Comment: @Mast usually when a department admits a student, they are usually committed to keepimg the student unless the student fails to meet a requirement. The department screwing up their budget is usually not grounds for dismissal. Assuming they didn't guarantee funding, they can cut the student''s funding.

Comment: @Mast: StrongBad is right. Students in good standing are not supposed to be "dismissed" by a US graduate program just because their advisor ran out of funding.

Comment: @aeismail Sure, they're not supposed to be dismissed like that. But is there anything in place preventing them to do it anyway?

Comment: @Mast: aeismail's "the department owes you the right to continue in the program" is surely describing a *moral* obligation, equivalent to your "they're not supposed to be dismissed like that", rather than a *mechanism* like your "anything in place preventing them to do it anyway". So I don't think you're actually disagreeing with him at all.

Comment: @ruakh: Actually, there is usually an offer letter that promises a certain term and amount of support if you’re in good standing. You could in theory sue the school if it failed to uphold the agreement. There would also be the harm in reputation if a school becomes known for kicking out students like that.

Comment: @Mast: legalities aside, a department saying "hey, we want you in our program, go ahead, leave what you are doing, get a visa, and travel far away from your country to get your degree here" and two years later saying "nah, screw whatever you did, now we cannot afford you so you have to go back with nothing to show for the last two years" is pretty poor etiquette.

Comment: @ruakh I never said I was disagreeing, I'm simply looking if there's more than moral and ethical grounds at play here. I completely agree with the answer provided.

Answer (score 13):

You are likely being given correct guidance that they cannot grant a second master's in the same discipline as the one you already have.  From what you describe, this probably does mean what you think it means at the end of semester.  You may find it helpful to consult an immigration attorney to lay out your options.